# PHP mysqli prepare statements own class

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to write a method for adding records to the database.

My method:

```
final public function newData($sql, $placeholder, $array) {
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param($placeholder, implode(",", $array));
  return $stmt->execute();
}
```

..................

```
// Code---Example
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, data) VALUES (?,?)";

$placeholder =  "ss";

final public function newData($sql, $placeholder, [$array]) {
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param($placeholder, implode(",", $array));
  return $stmt->execute();
 }
```

My problem is if I want to save several values with this method. I get a warning

> Warning: mysqli_stmt:: bind_param (): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in ##

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is here two `newData` methods? Which one do you use?

Comment: Second method is just Code-Example

Comment: Example of __what__?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `$stmt->bind_param()` that way. You would need to do argument unpacking because bind_param requires type and then each value as an argument.

```
final public function newData($sql, $placeholder, $array) {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param($placeholder, ...$array);
    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

Then use like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, data) VALUES (?,?)";

$result = $theDbClass->newData($sql, 'ss', ['foo', 'bar']);
```

Comment: Thank you! what do three points in this line mean?
$stmt->bind_param($placeholder, ...$array);
What they do? This method does not work without these points. I've never seen anything like it! :-)

Comment: Thats what  does the argument unpacking, https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking - its also very handy for functions like [pack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)